# How can I create or associate a super column to a column in Perl using Net::Cassandra?

Tags: perl, cassandra, thrift

How can I create or associate a super column to a column in Perl using [Net::Cassandra](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Cassandra)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Instead of asking us about the solution you think you need, tell us the problem you are trying to solve (http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Answer (score 6):

I just chatted with the module author and he doesn't understand the question. Then he guessed you want `batch_insert` which can take a supercolumn.

If that doesn't help, perhaps you step back, try to explain what you want to achieve and rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Best way, IMHO, is to submit a request to add information about super columns into documentation into [Net::Cassandra bug tracker](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Net-Cassandra).

Answer (score 2):

batch_insert is one way like daxim says; another way is to just use normal insert but specify super_column in the ColumnPath as well as the column_family.

It looks like Net::Cassandra stays pretty close to the thrift api, so this should be useful: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API